# how to debug using basheclipse

Tags: eclipse, bash, debugging

"Basheclipse installation issue" does not address my issue and thats why I ask a new question.

Hi, I am running Eclipse Luna on Windows 7

I followed all the instructions on http://sourceforge.net/projects/basheclipse/files/
I have never worked on Eclipse. I am stuck on 7th step(pasted below)

> 7) Switch to The Debug perspective. Start the debugging session. Launch "script.sh" from bash shell.

Please help me do this.
When I used the debug button it says "Launching new configuration has encountered an error Bash is already running."

I tried the run button and it says "Couldnt find Interpreters. Do you want to configure interpreters now?"

edit:ok the debug perspective is on now.

edit:ok looks like a bug
http://sourceforge.net/p/shelled/discussion/399718/thread/6272268c/
any way to circumvent this?

Comment: I too tried but debugging in bash eclipse not working for me also.

Comment: Anyone tried installing Eclipse and debugging on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

"Launching new configuration has encountered an error Bash is already running."

--> just relaunch your eclipse and then it will work without any problem.

"Anyone tried installing Eclipse and debugging on a Linux machine?"

--> yes. eclipse neon and jdk 8.
You can follow my tutorial at http://dietrichschroff.blogspot.de/2017/07/bash-enabling-eclipse-for-bash_14.html

[image]